# Should we merge the 'code-structure' and 'code-design' tags into the 'architecture' tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

If we consider the description of [architecture](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture):

> How code is structured. [...]

And the description of [code-structure](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-structure):

> Refers to ways of organizing code, so it can be easier to work with.

And the description of [code-design](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-design):

> 

(Yeah, there is none. And only 4 open questions.)

Should we make [code-structure](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-structure) and [code-design](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-design) as synonym of [architecture](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we should merge or create synonyms for those two tags, with the final master tag being [architecture](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture).

1. *"Refers to ways of organizing code"* is essentially the same thing as *"How code is structured"*.
2. "code-design", in this context, is really not about art, it's about how the code is structured, or organized, thus redirects the discussion to 1.

This makes all of the three tags quite the same. At the moment of this writing, 'code-design' has only 5 questions, 'code-structure' has 56 and 'architecture' has over 800 (not yet over 9000). This is why I'd suggest to keep 'architecture'.

Finally, if I were to ask someone

> Are you an expert in code design?

then

> Are you an expert in code-structure?

and then

> Are you an expert in architecture?

They'd probably get fed up and ask me why the hell am I asking three times the same question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not particularly enthused about [architecture](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture) at all (or [engine-architecture](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine-architecture), they both seem a bit too broad. However, the other tags you referenced certainly don't seem to add anything useful so I've merged them to `architecture` for now and set up appropriate synonyms.